# How to save checkbox state in the list in Android app?

Tags: android, listview, android-checkbox

How can I make a To-do app in Android Studio with checkbox in front of every item I write in the list and whenever I check or uncheck an item it should remain same whenever I open the app.Please share the code if anyone have for it.

Comment: If I was doing this, I would probably use SQLite to store the tasks and whether or not they're checked.  Then it would be pretty easy to query for them whenever the app is launched.

Answer (score 0):

On your main layout you should have 3 elements

1. EditText -- used to write the new task
2. Buttom  -- used to add a new task
3. ListView -- used to show your task lists

You should implement a List Adapter to manage your task data and a list view cell layout.

this layout should have a TextView to show your task and a CheckBox.

To keep your data when your app is opened, try to investigate about SQLite and how to used. I don't think much people like to share code but this is really simple, try it yourself